# Why are my onsuccess/onerror callbacks not called when using indexedDB?

Tags: javascript, html, indexeddb

Im trying to create a login form. I have a few usernames (objects) in the db. I've created a form which takes the user name submitted (primary key) and checks if it's in the db. However after the information passes through my loginCheck() method the page just refreshes and doesn't run the success nor the failed alerts I set to debug

JS:

```
//-------------USER DB------------------//
function startDB(){
    //sign in page elements
    logUser = document.getElementById('logUserName');
    logPass = document.getElementById('logPass');
    signin = document.getElementById('signin');
    signin.addEventListener('click',getLogin);

    //register page elements
    mainForm = document.getElementById('mainFormSidebar');
    mainForm.addEventListener('submit',addObject);
    fname = document.getElementById('fName');
    lName = document.getElementById('lName');
    users = document.getElementById('uName');
    pass = document.getElementById('password');
    email = document.getElementById('email');
    dob = document.getElementById('dob');
    phone = document.getElementById('phone');
    bio = document.getElementById('bio');
    terms = document.getElementById('terms');
    school = document.getElementById('school');
    gender = document.getElementsByName('gender');
    save = document.getElementById('save');
    reset = document.getElementById('reset'); 
    reset.addEventListener('click',clearForm);
    databox = document.getElementById('databox');



    //open DB
    var request = indexedDB.open('macroPlay'); 
    //if fails
    request.addEventListener('error', showerror); 
    //if succeeds
    request.addEventListener('success', start); 
    //if !exist, create.
    request.addEventListener('upgradeneeded', createdb); 

    //Create Admin account on launch

}
function showerror(e){
    alert('Error: ' + e.code + ' - ' + e.message);
}
function start(e){
    db = e.target.result;
    chkAdmin();
    showUsers();// Show all values in the object store
}
function createdb(e){
    var datababase = e.target.result;
    var myusers = datababase.createObjectStore('users', {keyPath: 'userName'});
}
function addObject(){
    if(confirm('Are you sure you want to resgister?')){
        var fName = document.getElementById('fName').value;
        var lName = document.getElementById('lName').value;
        var userName = document.getElementById('uName').value;
        var pass = document.getElementById('password').value;
        var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
        var dob = document.getElementById('dob').value;
        var phone = document.getElementById('phone').value;
        var bio = document.getElementById('bio').value;
        var terms = document.getElementById('terms').value;
        var school = document.getElementById('school').value;

        //May need to set a loop to find value of radio
        var gender;
        var radios = document.getElementsByName('gender');

        for (var i = 0, length = radios.length; i < length; i++) {
            if (radios[i].checked) {
                gender=radios[i].value;
            }
        }

        //set up transaction
        var mytransaction = db.transaction(['users'], "readwrite"); 

        //get object store
        var myusers = mytransaction.objectStore('users'); 

        //Add item
        var request = myusers.add(new getUser(userName,fName,lName,pass,email,dob,phone,bio,terms,school,gender));
    }

    // Show all results.
    mytransaction.addEventListener('complete', showUsers);  

    //Reset Form Fields
    resetForm();


}
function getUser(userName, fn, ln, pw, em, dob, tel, bio,tm, scl, gender){
    this.userName = userName;
    this.fn = fn;
    this.ln = ln;
    this.pw = pw;
    this.em = em;
    this.dob = dob;
    this.tel = tel;
    this.bio = bio;
    this.tm = tm;
    this.scl = scl;
    this.gender = gender;
}
function showUsers(){
    //reset box
    databox.innerHTML = ''; 
    //set the transaction 
    var mytransaction = db.transaction(['users']);
    //get object store
    var myusers = mytransaction.objectStore('users');
    //open the cursor and set an order
    var newcursor = myusers.openCursor(null,"prev");
    //show all users on successful load of DB
    newcursor.addEventListener('success',showUserList);
}
function showUserList(e){
    //var result = e.target.result;
    //databox.innerHTML = '<div>' + result.id + ' - ' + result.name + ' - ' + result.date + '</div>';
    var cursor = e.target.result; // Capture multiple return values as a cursor
    // Modify the databox to show the results 
    if (cursor){
   /*
        databox.innerHTML = '<div>' + 
           'Username'+ ' - ' + 
           'First'+ ' - ' + 
           'Last'+ ' - '+ 
           'Pass'+ ' - '+ 
           'Email'+ ' - '+ 
           'DOB'+ ' - '+
           'TEL'+ ' - '+ 
           'BIO'+ ' - '+ 
           'NEWS'+ ' - '+
           'TOS'+ ' - '+
           'SCL'+' - '+
           'Gender </div>';
   */

        databox.innerHTML += '<div>' + 
        cursor.value.userName + ' - ' + 
        cursor.value.fn+ ' - ' + 
        cursor.value.ln+ ' - '+ 
        cursor.value.pw+ ' - '+ 
        cursor.value.em+ ' - '+ 
        cursor.value.dob+ ' - '+
        cursor.value.tel+ ' - '+ 
        cursor.value.bio+ ' - '+ 
        cursor.value.tm+ ' - '+
        cursor.value.scl+' - '+
        cursor.value.gender+ 
        ' <input type="button" onclick="removeobject(\'' + cursor.value.userName + '\')" value="remove"/></div>';
            // Add a remove button as inserted HTML
        cursor.continue(); // Iterates over the cursor
    }
}
function removeobject(keyword){
    // Confirm the deletion
    if(confirm('Are you sure?')){ 
        // Set the transaction
        var mytransaction = db.transaction(['users'], "readwrite"); 
        // Get the object store
        var mystore = mytransaction.objectStore('users'); 
        // Delete the record with the chosen index
        var request = mystore.delete(keyword); 
        // If success, show the updated results
        mytransaction.addEventListener('complete', showUsers); 
    }
}

//reset functions
function clearForm(){
    //Clear form
    if(confirm('Clear all fields?')){
        resetForm();
    }
    showUserList();    
}
function resetForm(){
    //Reset form
    fname = document.getElementById('fName').value='';
    lName = document.getElementById('lName').value='';
    uName = document.getElementById('uName').value='';
    pass = document.getElementById('password').value='';
    email = document.getElementById('email').value='';
    dob = document.getElementById('dob').value='';
    phone = document.getElementById('phone').value='';
    bio = document.getElementById('bio').value='';
    nl = document.getElementById('nl').value='';
    terms = document.getElementById('terms').checked = false;
    school = document.getElementById('school').value='';
    gender = document.getElementsByName('gender').value='';
    showUserList();    
}


//------Create Admin Account-----//
function chkAdmin(){ 
     if(localStorage.getItem('admin')!="added"){             
        alert('Adding administrator Account');
        addAdmin();
    }
}
function addAdmin(){
    //set up transaction
        var mytransaction = db.transaction(['users'], "readwrite"); 
    //get object store
        var myusers = mytransaction.objectStore('users'); 
        var request = myusers.add(new getUser('admin','Shawn','Smith-Chao','admin'));  
        request.addEventListener('success',showUsers);   
    //Locally store that admin as been created  
        var admin = 'admin'; 
        var value = 'added';
        newItem(admin,value); 
}


//--------Retrieve User Date---------//
function getLogin(){
    alert('getLogin launched');
    var user = logUser.value;
    var pass = logPass.value;  
    alert('User: '+user+'  Pass: '+pass+"   sent to loginCheck");
    loginCheck(user,pass);
    alert ('user/pass checked');
}

function loginCheck(user,pass){
    var transaction = db.transaction(['users']);   
    var mystore = transaction.objectStore('users');  
    alert('User table opened');
    var request = transaction.get(user);
    alert('passed the get user request');
    request.onerror = function (event){
        alert("username does not exist");
    };
    request.onsuccess =function (event){
         alert('request was successful');
        /*alert("Welcome "+ request.result.userName);*/
        //run function populating all fields

    }
}
```

I put an alert at the start(e) function and it seems to be getting called right after the alert that displays the user/pass. Im looking around I can't figure out what keeps calling it.

Also, if I change my loginCheck to this, the alert runs and the code progresses a bit further alert ('user/pass checked'); but then start(e) get's called yet again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The indexeddb API works asynchronous, that is why the alerts don't show up in the order you are thinking. Because the API is asynchronous means that all other code will execute while you are waiting for the asynchronous call to finish.

Comment: Would you happen to know why at the end of all functions, the start(e) method is being called? I need to have the form populate with the users information when he logs in so that they can update it if need be. But right after I run my populate function, start(e) runs, and everything is wiped.

Comment: Are you sure there is data in your store?

Comment: I believe so. I've created a function to populate the form with all the users information and that works, but whenever it's done, it just refreshes again and runs start(e). Im not sure if this is normal and if I should be using sessionStorage to capture all the information i need and populate the fields based on that

Comment: are you sure that the start method isn't called on other places? Also the startDB method is maybe called multiple times?

Comment: hey @Kristof, I think the problem was that I was running the populate function within the indexedDB transaction, so once it completed the start(e) was called because of an eventListener looking for "success". I was actually really hoping you could take a look at this question for me please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15540127/stored-value-generating-object-htmlinputelement