# Stored value generating [object HTMLInputElement]

Tags: javascript, html, object, indexeddb

I have an indexedDB and using it for a login function. I'm trying to populate a form with the users information when they log in. However the form populates with [object HTMLInputElement] instead of the users info.

This is where I take the user (db key) to access the Object (the user)

EDITThis is my site where it's running: http://www3.carleton.ca/clubs/sissa/html5/admin.html
My site editor is updating it as I save, so there may be changes to the site script as I try new things.

This is where I take the user (db key) to access the Object (the user)

```
function loginCheck(user,pass){    db.transaction("users").objectStore("users").get(user).onsuccess = function(event) {
    var loggedUser = event.target.result;
        if(!loggedUser){
            alert('Sorry, Username does not exist. Please try again.');
        }else if(pass !== loggedUser.pw ){
            alert('Incorrect log in combination. Please try again.');
            }else{loggedIn(loggedUser);}        
    }    
}
function loggedIn(loggedUser){
    var u=loggedUser;
    alert('Welcome '+u.fn+' '+u.ln+' to Macroplay');

    //function to populate fields 
    alert('get values called'); 
    getValues(u);

    //session store     
    var signedin = 'user';
    var username = u.userName;
    newLocal(signedin,username);
    alert('local storage set'); 
}
```

I use this function getValues to store the various fields I want from the object.

**EDIT: I declared the variable test as global and stored the users first name (fn). The alerts show the correct name but the populate still gives me undefined.**

```
    var test;
function getValues(loggedUser){
    var u = loggedUser;
    alert('storing first name');
    test = u.fn;
    alert('First name = '+test);
    lName = u.ln; 
    users = u.userName;
    pass = u.pw;
    email = u.em;
    dob = u.dob;
    tel = u.tel;
    bio = u.bio;
    school = u.scl; 
    alert('user values stored');  
    if(u.gender == 'M'){
        gender[0].checked= true ;
    }else{gender[1].checked= true ;}        
}
```

This is the function I use to populate the form that's giving me  [object HTMLInputElement]

```
function populateFields(){
    alert('Name of populated field: '+test);
    fName.value = test;
    lName.value = lName;
    users.value = users;
    pass.value = pass;
    email.value = email;
    dob.value = dob;
    tel.value = tel; 
    bio.value = bio;
    terms.disabled = true;
    school.value = school;  
    alert('populate fields done');

    save.value = 'Update';
    signin.innerHTML = 'Log Out';
    registerLabel.innerHTML = 'Account Information';

     //open user info form
    var accountInfo = document.getElementsByTagName('details');
    accountInfo[1].open = open;
}
```

Comment: Do not do authentication in client-side JavaScript. The code you posted shows me how to discover the passwords of every user in your database using nothing but a web browser.  Authentication **must** be done on a server.  There must exist **no** API that could return a user's password to client-side JavaScript.

Comment: This is for a school assignment. We have to do it using JavaScript and the indexedDB API

Comment: Change schools.  :)  Seriously, if your instructor is suggesting you retrieve passwords in client side JavaScript, even as an exercise, I take issue with the curriculum.

Comment: It's a commerce course on HTML5. He just wants us to use the indexedDB for this assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just look at one line:

```
fName.value = fName
```

You are setting the `value` property of `fName` to `fName` itself.

Rather than creating numerous global variables, just use `loggedUser` directly in `populateFields()`:

```
fName.value = loggedUser.fn;
```

**Edit:** Looking at [your site](http://www3.carleton.ca/clubs/sissa/html5/admin.html), I see the important bit you left out.  `populateFields()` is being called *after* the page reloads.  So, **`populateFields()` does not have access to any variable created before the page reloaded**.

Since I'm helping you with homework, I don't want to just hand you the answer on a silver platter.  The trick is that the user data must be retrieved from the database and made available to `populateFields()` before it is called, or from within the function.  You *can* make the user object available as a global variable, but it may be better to pass it in as a parameter.

You probably want to also cancel the form submission:

```
document.getElementById("loginForm").onsubmit = function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

And then just call `populateFields()` directly from `loggedIn()` instead of `getValues()`.

Comment: I tried this but I don't think loggedUser will work in populateFields() because it's outside the indexedDB transaction. Im getting loggedUser undefined.

Comment: Expose `loggedUser` as a global variable.

Comment: I removed the var from loggedUser from the loginCheck() but that didn't change anything. Im getting error: cannot read fn from undefined.

Comment: hello @gilly3, you said i need to make the data available to populateFields() before it's called. I tried to do this by storing the data in a global variable called test (edited OP/site) and then use that test variable in populate Fields but it returned undefined in the textbox. Also, I'm not calling populateFields() from getValues(), it's running from start(e) when the page loads to see if anyone is logged in. Is that incorrect? Thank you.

Comment: Also, Im not sure I understand why I should cancel the form submission?

Comment: @Batman - When you reload the page, all your variables are gone and you start over from scratch.  Right now your code captures the user data and stores it in a variable, then it reloads the page by allowing the form to be submitted. When the page loads again, your code tries to use the variable that you created before the form submission.  But it's gone! The page was reloaded! Variables do not persist between page loads.

Comment: Oh so my page automatically reloads when the form submits. I didn't know that. I need the information to remain stored even if the user leaves the page (kinda like, "keep me logged in"). Do you think I should store each piece of user data using local storage? Could that fix my issues?

Comment: That's the whole point of using indexedDB isn't it?  That the data is always available?  You've already got username available in localstorage and that's all you need to retrieve the user from indexedDB.  Just retrieve the data from indexedDB.  (And do cancel the form submission.)

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't sure if that was a yes to my question of storing everything using the localStorage. So like uesrname,name,last,tel, etc  then using something like fname.value = localStorage.getItem(fname);  Sorry if I asked a lot of questions, this is all very new to me.

Also, i've placed the code for cancelling form submission in getValue()? It's the last method before the end of the DB transaction so I thought that would work.

Comment: No, retrieve the data from the database, not localStorage.  Retrieve the username from localStorage and use it to get the user details from the database.

Comment: No, `getValue()` will not work.  Use `getLogin(e)` instead. It would be best to use the `form.onsubmit` handler, but `getLogin()` is probably good enough.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26678/discussion-between-gilly3-and-batman)

Comment: I haven't gotten it to work just yet but just based on what you're saying the getValues() function is completely unnecessary right? Because if the page reloads the stored values are gone so there's no point to that function. Correct?

Comment: Let's [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26678/discussion-between-gilly3-and-batman)